# How do I put the name of the IBAction pressed on my main view controller in a NSString on my modal view?

Tags: view, nsstring, modal-dialog, ibaction

I have about ten IBActions on my main view that go to the same modal view and I need to know how to see what IBActon was pressed to get there and put that in a NSString on the modal view.

Here's the code that sends you to the modal view. The only difference in the IBActions is the name. Like playMovie: and playMovie2: and so on.

```
-(IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender{
VideoSubViewController *subView = [[[VideoSubViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
[subView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
[self presentModalViewController:subView animated:YES];}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `init*` on the modal view that takes that information. The usage would be:

```
VideoSubViewController *subView = 
  [[[VideoSubViewController alloc] initForAction:@"playMovie"] autorelease];
```

You then store that information in the view instance in order to use it.